# how to format number to currency by currency name in JavaScript/Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, currency

How to format  number to currency by currency name?

I have dynamic numbers with only currency name ( ex: USD,INR etc). I don't have any local codes (like, en-US).

I would try this below way. But it is asking to provide local code('en-US').

```
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD',
});

formatter.format(2500)
```

But I don't have *'en-US'* in my data base. I have only currency Name and Number.

So how could I format the the number to currency by Currency name?

Answer (score 2):

Just pass `undefined` for the locale?

```js
const getFormattedCurrency = (currency, amount) => new Intl.NumberFormat(undefined, {
  style: 'currency',
  currency,
}).format(amount);

console.log(getFormattedCurrency('USD', 2500));
console.log(getFormattedCurrency('JPY', 2500));
console.log(getFormattedCurrency('EUR', 2500));
console.log(getFormattedCurrency('CNY', 2500));
console.log(getFormattedCurrency('AUD', 2500));
console.log(getFormattedCurrency('INR', 2500));
```